# How can I create a 3D line object in Matlab which I can light using a light object?

Tags: matlab, 3d, line, lighting

I have 3 vectors which specify the X, Y, and Z coordinates of various points on a line in 3-space.  I plot them using plot3, i.e.

```
plot3(X,Y,Z,'go-','LineWidth',4,'MarkerSize',32);
grid on
```

to get a 3D line object on a grid.  I would like to be able to change the lighting on the object using a command like lightangle, but it seems to only work with objects created with surf, mesh, etc.  Does anyone have a good way to turn my line into an object which I can adjust the lighting of?

Thanks,
Chris

Comment: I believe that in most 3D graphic engines, Matlab included, lighting only affects 2D surfaces and not edges, so you can't apply lighting to a line.

Comment: create a `cylinder` and apply a 3D rotation based on your vector

Answer (score 0):

Line objects do not have lighting properties in Matlab, but patch edges do.

Plot a "line" with

```
% NaNs make the patch effectively faceless, with only an edge
p = patch([X,nan], [Y,nan], [Z,nan], 'k', ...
    'EdgeColor', 'g', 'EdgeLighting', 'Gouraud');
```

and you now have a property for the "line" `p` called

```
p.VertexNormals % or get(p, 'VertexNormals') in pre-2014b
```

This defines the normal vectors for the line, whose direction is used to calculate the effect of lighting. By default `p.VertexNormals` will all be `[0, 0, 1]` for edges, pointing down the Z-axis. You can manually replace `VertexNormals` to  alter the effect of lighting on each patch edge vertex.

Normal vectors that point toward a light mean a point on the object will appear brighter, those that point away will appear darker.